# How 'ld change dbfield value onclick the image from( boolean) 0 to 1

Tags: javascript

Here is my code in view,

```
 <span><a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}"><img alt="" 
src="http://school.glwh.org/wp-content/uploads/bigstock-vector-green-
positive-checkmar-16955600.jpg" 
        style="height: 85px; width: 80px" id="imgClickAndChange"
```

onclick="changeImage()"  />

And in controller,

```
public function postApprove($id)
{
     $application = Move::where('id', '=', e($id))->first();
if($application)
{
    $application->approved = 1;
    $application->save();
  return redirect()->route('driver');
}
```

This coe changes the dbfield value to '1' onclick but when do another click it's value 'ld be '0' for that how 'ld I change my code

Comment: `$application->approved = 1-$application->approved;` switches 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your code